# How to Force NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event to Fire on Page Load

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using the following event to gather network information, but I need the information to be updated and populate my view when the page is first navigated to, as well as when network changes occur. How might I force the following event to fire in the OnNavigatedTo event?

```
// Subscribe to the NetworkAvailabilityChanged event
DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new EventHandler<NetworkNotificationEventArgs>(ChangeDetected);


...


void ChangeDetected(object sender, NetworkNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ChangeDetected` is a method. Just call it in the `OnNavigatedTo` event.

```
ChangeDetected(this, new NetworkNotificationEventArgs());
```

Comment: I get an error that says `The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkNotificationEventArgs' has no constructors defined.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't force that event to fire (Someone correct me if I'm wrong).

From what I can see in your question you want to first check if the network is available when the page is navigated to. This can be done like the following:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

....

protected virtual void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   bool isAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

   MessageBox.Show(isAvailable.ToString());
}
```

After doing some basic searching I was able to find this resource directly from Microsoft explaining how to use the event including the page(xaml) and the code(c#) at this link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try running your Message box code in the UI thread, instead of the main thread where it checks for the Connectivity change.

```
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(isAvailable.ToString());
    });
```